# Command prompt run .bat file

Tags: windows-10, command-line

I have to start command prompt with "geth" command every time Windows 10 opens, I know how to add files to autostart in windows but I have no idea how to instruct the geth.bat file to make the command geth to initiate. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do note, if you name your .bat or .cmd file the same as the executable you try to open, and then execute the bat file, it will call itself rather than the executable. So geth.bat will start geth.bat, not geth.exe. So make sure you rename geth.bat to something else. For example geth1.bat or start_geth.bat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By `geth`, I am assuming you mean [go-ethereum](https://geth.ethereum.org/downloads/).

To run `geth` in a single command window, simply use something like e.g.

```
 geth help
```

To spawn `geth` in a new command window (not the same window as the batch file), prefix your command with `cmd /k start` e.g.

```
cmd /k start geth help
```

---

*Notes*

- `help` is obviously an example and can be any options you wish.
- If your program isn't registered in your Path, you will need to use its full location instead e.g. `C:\some\path\geth.exe`.
- As @LPChip points out in the comments, to avoid issues, do not name your batch file exactly the same as the executable (i.e. don't use `geth.bat`).

Comment: hi tsk for the reply, yes is the geth I write in command prompt to update or download the blockchain, so if I write "geth" in a bat file only nothing else, and add to autostart it will open command prompt and run geth automatically?

Comment: Yes, assuming this is how you use it from the command prompt normally. If `geth` isn't registered in your Path variable, you may have to use its full location e.g. `C:\some\path\geth.exe`.

Answer (score 1):

Just put whatever command line commands you use to start geth (whatever that is) into a file called (for example) "start_geth.bat" using a text editor.  Then as you say, add that file to windows autostart.

See a [howto](https://fossbytes.com/what-is-a-batch-file-in-windows-how-to-create-a-batch-file/) from fossbytes.

Scroll down to 'Things to know before creating a batch file', then 'How to create a batch file in Windows' to skip the whys & wherefores.